# How does Pinterest calculate and retrieve popular pins?

Tags: algorithm, pinterest

How does Pinterest calculate and retrieve popular pins?
I guess it has to be with repins/likes/clicks with some relation to the time each was done.
But since the loading of these items is done pretty fast I would guess they pre-process this ranking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472365/what-is-the-pinterests-popular-pins-algorithm

Comment: Ya, I saw that, it doesn't my question nor does it talk about how do they retrieve/store it.